# MongoDB Server Configuration

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, database-connection, database

I have a MongoDB server running on my localhost. I wrote a simple Python program that reads/writes to the database using "localhost"; however, I want to give other clients access to my MongoDB server. For now, I am not concerned about access security and would like to grant access to anyone. How should I configure the Mongo Server to do this?

Here is the simple program connecting to localhost.

```
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    connection = MongoClient("Localhost")
    db = connection.hockey.players
    results = db.find()
    print()
    print('+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-')
    for record in results:
        print(record['name'] + ',',record['position'])
    connection.close()
```

The error message I'm getting:
    File "C:/Users/Peter/PycharmProjects/Test/helloWorld.py", line 8, in 
    for record in results:
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1097, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1019, in _refresh self.__read_concern))
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 850, in __send_message **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 777, in _send_message_with_response server = topology.select_server(selector)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 142, in select_server address))
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 118, in select_servers self._error_message(selector))
    pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: x.y.z.w:27017: timed out

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Below is my current localhost setup that works fine if I run it on my client which hosts the MongoDB. [Current setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFNnz.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give them your ip address and the port number (Default:27017) to connect to your server. Also edit the `bindIp` in the `mongod.conf` file as `bindIp: 0.0.0.0`. Ask them to connect to your database by using something like:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient("mongodb://your_ip:yourport")
```

If you're on windows, create the configuration file `mongod.cfg`. And add the entry as

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: c:\data\db
net:
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0
    port: 27017
```

Make sure you've already created `log` and `db` folder or change the path where your data and log folder are located.
Start the mongodb by specyfying thr configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick follow up. I didn't find the config file so I created one in the MongoDb bin directory. I set the bindIp flag 0.0.0.0. I started the MongoDb server using this config file. When I run the app with "localhost" connection string, it runs properly. However, when I changed the localhost to "mongodb://my_ip:27017", I am still timing out

Comment: Which os are you using ? If it's linux the file will be located in `/etc/mongod.conf` .

Comment: The MongoDB server seems to be reading this config file when I type cmd: mongod --config "<PATH>/bin/mongodb.conf". I was mocking with some of the parameters I saw some error messages.

Comment: Thank you this works! Also, my problem was that I was using the machine public IP address instead of private

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you local interface is up. It should explain the timeout.

```
ifup lo
```